# How do I move my logo from the center to left (Pixgraphy theme)

Tags: css, logo

I am trying to move my logo from the center of my page to the left side.

I am using the "Pixgraphy" theme by "freesia" and it doesn't allow me to move it in the template

whenever I try to paste custom CSS code in, it wont do anything and I'm a little afraid editing directly in the .php file due to previous syntax errors

[image: I want the logo to move to the leftmo]

Hope someone out there can help me

( ps: I am not very skilled in either CSS/HTML so I would appreciate some very simple/basic instructions )

Thanks in advance

Best regards

Alfred

Comment: WPSE is good for questions that are specific to WordPress development issues. Generic HTML/CSS/JavaScript questions are better suitable for [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com). Please read [the topics here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/asking) to know how to ask a good question in WPSE.

Answer (score 0):

use `container-fluid` class instead of `container` in header.php file of Pixgraphy theme.

Remove `text-align: center` and `margin: 0 auto` from the ID `site-branding` in your style.css. You can also overwrite it using custom stylesheet editor.

Also, add below style to resolve your issue.

```
#site-branding {
  float: left;
}
```

Thanks